# Generating pdf in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Following is my code to generate the pdf. I am using label for pdf. Code is not giving any error but the pdf is also not Generating.

```
    Dim flname As String = "FeedbackReport"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & flname)
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    Dim frm As New HtmlForm()

    rp.Parent.Controls.Add(frm)
    'GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    '  frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    frm.Controls.Add(rp)
    'frm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
    frm.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())

    ' Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize._11X17, 35.0F, 35.0F, 30.0F, 30.0F)
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize._11X17, 20.0F, 20.0F, 30.0F, 30.0F)
    FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()

    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.[End]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use itextsharp for generating pdf

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

for demo see following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203481/HTML-convert-to-PDF-using-itextsharp

Comment: Except that iTextSharp is licensed under the Affero GPL which really isn't suitable for a lot of projects.